# MySQL select where not()..and...and. (or...or)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select data from one table.

This query work well:

```
SELECT * FROM game WHERE NOT (type = 'unity') 
AND (cat_id='3d' OR cat2_id='3d' OR cat3_id='3d') 
ORDER BY hits desc limit 120, 70
```

But I need run it with published=1

```
SELECT * FROM game WHERE NOT (type = 'unity') 
AND (cat_id='3d' OR cat2_id='3d' OR cat3_id='3d') 
AND published=1
ORDER BY hits desc limit 120, 70
```

At this point I see result 0 rows but it should be 50 rows.

Comment: That means the condition is not matching with the extra condition `published=1` and no records returning

Comment: so can we delete the question?

Comment: As I write it should by 50 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the condition is not matching with the extra condition `AND published=1` and so no records returning. Again instead of saying `NOT (type = 'unity')` it's much redable if you say `(type != 'unity')`.

You can try modifying your query a bit like below

```
SELECT * FROM game 
WHERE (type != 'unity') 
AND published=1 
AND '3d' in (cat_id, cat2_id, cat3_id) 
ORDER BY hits desc 
limit 120, 70;
```

If you really sure that with new condition `published=1` it should return 50 rows then try adding that condition as a outer query condition with the SQL which works well like below and see what result it returns.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM game WHERE NOT (type = 'unity') 
AND (cat_id='3d' OR cat2_id='3d' OR cat3_id='3d') 
ORDER BY hits desc limit 120, 70
) xxx WHERE published=1;
```